# Choices defined for model fields not being enforced?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

So I've defined some fields as choices:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Text language.                                                                                 
    ENGLISH = 'eng'                                                                                   
    FRENCH  = 'fr'                                                                                   

    LANGUAGES_CHOICES = [                                                                            
        (ENGLISH, 'English'),                                                                        
        (FRENCH, 'French'),                                                                          
    ]                                                                                                

    language = models.CharField(                                                                     
            max_length=max(len(language) for language in LANGUAGES_CHOICES),                         
            choices=LANGUAGES_CHOICES,                                                               
            blank=False,                                                                             
            null=True)
```

However, I can do `MyModel(language='hurhurhur').save()` without any error or complaint. What am I missing?

Comment: do `python manage.py dbshell` and `desc appname_mymodel` and see what the length attribute is set to. Looking at your code, `max_length=2`, but clearly not the case.

Comment: Another thing- try `MyModel.objects.create(language='hurhurhur')` You will get the error

Comment: @karthikr: I like it. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django validates a model when you validate a modelform, or if you explicitly call modelinst.full_clean()   Calling modelinst.save() doesn't validate.

Comment: Is there any way I can enable calling `full_clean()` on every save, short of overriding the `save` method?

Comment: Not really. I think the easiest way is to create a base class that all your models derive from which overrides save, and have that base class inherit from the django model class.