# Django restrict data that can be given to model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model in django:

```
class Cast(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length = 7)

    def __str__(self):
        return(f"{self.kind} || {self.count} || {self.modified.strftime('%x')}")
```

But I want the 'kind' field to only take one of the following values: up, down, strange, charm, top, or bottom. How can I enforce this in the database or can this only be enforced in the views when taking in data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) should do?

```
class Cast(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    kind = models.CharField(
        max_length=7,
        choices=(
            ("up", "Up"),
            ("down", "Down"),
            ("strange", "Strange"),
            ("charm", "Charm"),
            ("top", "Top"),
            ("bottom", "Bottom")
        )
    )
```

Although in many occasions I've seen it used as a SmallInteger to save space in the database: In the DB you store a number, and in your Admin area you'll see a drop down with the "human friendly" choices.

```
kind = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    choices=(
        (1, "Up"),
        (2, "Down"),
        (3, "Strange"),
        (4, "Charm"),
        (5, "Top"),
        (6, "Bottom")
    )
)
```

See:

[image: Choices in action]

This is **not enforced at the DB level** (see [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26131) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924700/choices-defined-for-model-fields-not-being-enforced)) which means you still can do:

```
>>> c = Cast.objects.first()
>>> c.kind = 70
>>> c.save()
```

but it is enforced in the Admin. If you need it to be enforced in a lower level, I suggest you go with [Noah Lc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48040063/289011).

As far as I understand, that is (still) not 100% enforced: You can still do bulk updates that don't go through the `.save()` method of the model; meaning: doing `Cast.objects.all().update(kind=70)` would still set an invalid value (`70`) in the `kind` field, but his solution is, indeed, one step "lower" than the Admin *choices*. You won't be able to do model updates that go through the `.save()` method of the instance. Meaning, you won't be allowed to do this:

```
>>> c=Cast.objects.first()
>>> c.kind=70
>>> c.save()
```

If you do need REAL database enforcement, you will need to actually check your databases's possibilities and add a constraint on the `cast.kind` column.

For instance, for Postgres (and probably for most of other SQL flavors) you could create a new migration that did this:

```
from django.db import migrations


def add_kind_constraint(apps, schema_editor):
    table = apps.get_model('stackoverflow', 'Cast')._meta.db_table
    schema_editor.execute("ALTER TABLE %s ADD CONSTRAINT check_cast_kind"
                          " CHECK (kind IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) )" % table)


def remove_kind_constraint(apps, schema_editor):
    table = apps.get_model('stackoverflow', 'Cast')._meta.db_table
    schema_editor.execute("ALTER TABLE %s DROP CONSTRAINT check_cast_kind" % table)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('stackoverflow', '0003_auto_20171231_0526'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_kind_constraint, reverse_code=remove_kind_constraint)
    ]
```

And then yeah... You'd be 100% secured (the check doesn't depend on Django: now is in the hands of your database engine):

```
>>> c = Cast.objects.all().update(kind=70)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: new row for relation "stackoverflow_cast" violates check constraint "check_cast_kind"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 1, 70, 1).
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it inside the save method of your model:

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    mylist = ['up', 'down', 'strange', 'charm',....]
    if self.kind in mylist:
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
       raise Exception, "kind take only one of the following values: up, down, strange, charm,...."
```